# Branch from a branch: moving to a normal branch

Tags: svn, branch

I normally create branches from trunk, work on them, and eventually reintegrate them back into trunk.

Sometimes I'll create a branch Y from another branch X, so I can start with X's code. Normally I'll reintegrate Y into X first, then reintegrate X into trunk.

```
Y --> X --> trunk
```

But what if I want to reintegrate X into trunk first, and I no longer want Y to depend on X? In other words, I want Y to be a normal branch, so that I can merge it directly to and from trunk, without going through X.

```
Y --> trunk
X --> trunk
```

What should I do? One approach would be to create a new branch, and merge all of Y's changes into it. But I'd like to keep using Y if possible, so I don't lose track of its history. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subversion does not track any dependencies between branches. It only keeps the history and the history of merges.

When you merge Y to X svn inserts the information about the merge that just happened. When you merge X back to trunk, this information is propagated to trunk. This way, a change will never be applied twice on consequent merges. No matter how these merges were made.

You should just merge X into trunk, and then work with Y like X never existed. Merge in to trunk if you want or just keep working on it whether you want.

In svn branches have no dependencies or whatsoever.

Comment: But it pays attention to the common ancestor when you merge. So will it find the right common ancestor if I merge trunk into Y (or vice-versa)? It seems like, at the very least, if I reintegrate X into trunk, I'll need to block that revision from Y.

Comment: The moment you branched Y from X, is the last time Y get any changes from X. Y is no longer affected by any actions done on X. Be it merge, move or delete.

Comment: Just to clarify, I've been merging X into Y. So any changes that were in X are also in Y. Therefore, if I reintegrate X into trunk, that will duplicate those changes in trunk. So I think I'll need to block that revision from being merged back into Y.

Comment: The merge information is stored in svn property "svn:mergeinfo" in the destination branch. In your case, the information about merge will be stored in both Y and in trunk. So when you will merge Y into trunk, svn will detect it and merge it accordingly.

Comment: OK, I tried this and it worked. After I reintegrated X into trunk, I did a record-only merge from trunk into X, to block that revision from being merged twice. Then I merged X into Y, and the blocked revision is now blocked from Y too. Now I'm able to merge from trunk into Y, and reintegrate from Y into trunk.